# Complete printing N lines from text files

Tags: python

Im new to python and im trying to write a script that print out the the first N lines from each text file in a directory that i give as a user input. I cannot make this work. any help will be appreciate it.

the file path i enter is /home/myprofile/

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob, os
dirpath=input("Enter path: ")
for file in glob.glob(dirpath + "*.txt" ):
        print(file)
        with open("file") as myfile:
        head = [next(myfile) for 2 in xrange(2)]
        print head
```

Comment: This is a general programming question, so please ask on Stack Overflow instead. But you'll want to clarify the question first. Your script has a few different problems.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob, os
dirpath=raw_input("Enter path: ")

for file in glob.glob(dirpath+"/*.txt" ):
    print(file)
    with open(file) as myfile:
        for x in range(0, 5):
            print myfile.readline().rstrip() #rstrip to remove \n
```

Happy to edit if it doesn't fit.